# Eigenvalue problem $−\psi''(x) − (ix)^ N \psi(x) = E\psi(x)$ in complex plane

Tags: schroedinger-equation, boundary-conditions, eigenvalue, complex-numbers, asymptotics

To find the eigenvalue in the complex plane of $x$ for one dimensional Schrodinger equation
$$
−ψ''(x) − (ix)^ N ψ(x) = Eψ(x).
$$
where $N$ can be any **real** number, the boundary condition  $ψ(x) → 0$ as $|x| → ∞$ causes a great difficulty for numerical method, because there are infinite number of contour paths which go from zero to complex infinity.

Bender et al on their [**paper**](http://arxiv.org/abs/physics/9712001) only considered the contour paths (e.g. the black path on the following figure) which are **entirely** confined in two Stokes wedges symmetric with respect to the imaginary axis. Based on my understanding on what they say, each asymptotic series expansion for $ψ(x)$ is only valid within certain sector or wedge, therefore for any path which is outside of these two wedges, the corresponding asymptotic series is no longer asymptotic to the value of the function $ψ(x)$ . However, there exists a new, unique and valid asymptotic series for $ψ(x)$ outside the wedge. Yet, this new asymptotic series, say $f(x)$, does not satisfy the boundary condition  $f(x) → 0$ as $|x| → ∞$ .

[image]

**My question**:
I don't really understand why the contour path has to be entirely inside the Stokes sector. How about the red and yellow path shown on the figure above?
They are partly inside the Stokes wedges. The red path starts from the complex infinity which lies inside the right Stokes wedge and then approaches the origin zero from the left Stokes wedge, so that only the middle part of the red path lies outside the two Stokes sectors. The yellow path starts from the complex infinity which lies inside the right Stokes wedge and then approaches the origin zero inside the right Stokes wedge again. Why do these red and yellow paths have to be excluded please? If we integrate along anyone of these two paths, does it yield finite eigenvalue and exponentially decayed eigenfunction or not? Why?

Comment: At the bottom of page 2, Bender et al. say "The differential equation (2) may be integrated on any path in the complex-x plane so long as the ends of the path approach complex infinity inside the left wedge and
the right wedge [14]."  That sounds like your red and yellow paths would be okay then.

Comment: @user2309840  Thank you! Do you know any simple explanation why Bender said this on his paper? If you read his [**textbook**](http://www.amazon.com/Advanced-Mathematical-Methods-Scientists-Engineers/dp/0387989315) on the page 135, he clearly listed some path as "bad path" even if the "bad path" eventually connected the two desired points. Also, in the section 3.7 on his textbook, when he extended the asymptotic relations in the complex plane, he had to exclude all the paths which rotated around the irregular singular point.